# Error when unit testing a VS project that uses winsqlite3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, sqlite

I have a project in Visual Studio 2017 that runs some code that uses winsqlite3. The project executes fine, I have winsqlite3 as an additional linker dependency. I added a test project to write unit tests for this code. When I add winsqlite3.lib as an additional linker dependency in my unit test project, I get the error message
`Unable to start program 'C:\my\path\project.dll'. C:\my\path\project.dll is not a valid Win32 application.`

But without this dependency I get linker errors. How do I resolve this?

I am building for x64, as a console application.

Comment: Go to your project's configuration Properties and see what "Debugging" says is the program that will be launched.

Comment: It said it would be launched as a dll - what are you asking specifically?

Comment: You don't launch DLL's.  You launch applications that will use your DLL.  So in the "Debugging" option, you give the name of the executable that will use your DLL.